# Is there anyway to execute a string in apex which would be similar to javascript eval() function

Tags: apex

I have a requiremnt where a mathematical expression is embedded in an apex string variable and  I need to evaluate that expression value.  Is there any way to do this? Any workaround for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How complicated is this expression? It seems like you're going to have to parse it out yourself.

Comment: Apex Code's executeAnonymous is the closest you get to JavaScript eval, but it doesn't work the same way. Any variables don't persist outside the executeAnonymous call, no return value is possible, and it runs in a separate execution context.

Comment: maybe you can implement it with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: Related [How to eval string expression in salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-eval-string-expression-in-salesforce)

Answer (score 1):

No, apex does not have a way to evaluate a string at runtime. You could write your own parser, but it wouldn't be easy. You'd have to find a way to do this in JavaScript if your logic has any sort of UI/page layer.

Here are a few examples from questions asked here previously:
[Evaluate expressions/conditions in apex code ? (which are stored in string/text)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/evaluate-expressions-conditions-in-apex-code-which-are-stored-in-string-text)